# What does the "Assault" powerup do?

Tags: paranautical-activity

What does the Assault powerup (pictured below as a red reticle) do?

[image: Assault powerup pictured]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the duration of the powerup, firing rate and damage are significantly increased.